# virtualenv: can't find '__main__' module

Tags: linux, python, pip, virtualenv

`$ virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ~/PyVEnv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3/usr/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-16.3.0-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py'`

I'm trying to install virtualenv in my friend's laptop which I guessed will be easier because I had done it once *successfully* on my laptop, but this is persistent!

`$ virtualenv --version
16.3.0
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)`

`Debian 9.7`

**Update:**
With *recent pip* (on friend's laptop) I installed virtualenv, then I found that it was absurd and that it must be installed with the deb packages, so I did it the *apt-get way* and then uninstalled the one which is under pip.

I had encountered some issues in OS installation (on friend's laptop). The usb wouldn't boot in UEFI mode (made bootable by PowerISO), but then I tried creating a bootable USB using balenaEtcher, from my Laptop (which has only BIOS) and for no reason it created an EFI partition in the USB. Anyway then, Debian installation went smoothly in UEFI mode (on friend's laptop). [Laptop description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Mz8.png)

I had updated to Windows 10 and only then I installed Debian.

What am I forgetting?

Comment: You are trying to create python3 env by running virtualenv installed in "python2.7" Do you have ``virtualenv3`` or ``virtualenv3.5``? You may need ``pip3 install virtualenv``

Comment: I removed the virtualenv distro package.
Running `pip3 list` I see `virtualenv` against version `15.1.0`, uninstalling that with `pip3 uninstall virtualenv` leads me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092519)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

When I run `pip3 uninstall virtualenv` -> leads me [StackOverflow Q.No. 41092519](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092519/). So I moved the `*virtualenv` to /home. Then I opened `Synaptic Package Manager` and searched for `virtualenv` and marked it for complete removal --> `Apply`. I also ran `sudo apt-get remove virtualenv` & `sudo apt-get purge virtualenv`. Lastly I `Rebooted` and ran `virtualenv --version` it gave me `16.3.0`

That *freaked* me out. A good Samaritan told me to run `(head -1 $(which virtualenv) | cut -d! -f2) -c 'import virtualenv; print(virtualenv.__file__)'`. And that opened my eyes, it told me that this `"virtualenv"` was the one under Python2.7 just as our friend mentioned in the comments to the question, above. But I had never installed install `pip` for `python2` (but it was because I ran `sudo easy_install virtualenv`).

**Solution Begins Here:**

# So then I installed `pip` and uninstalled `virtualenv` using the same.

# Ran `pip3 install virtualenv`

# Ran `python3 -c 'import virtualenv; print(virtualenv.__file__)'` which gave me the path to `virtualenv under python3` which was `~/.local/bin`.

# Amended `.bashrc` to add `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH`

That's it. Hope it helps somebody someday...

You can follow the conversation [VirtualenvIssue1310@Github](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1310)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this. You can actually use

```
sudo virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ~/PyVEnv
```

and this should work.